# cannot install php5-mysql

Tags: server, apt, php, mysql

I have ubuntu 32bit server (14.04), running php5,
I am trying to install php5-mysql

but I get a dependancy error. How can i fix this?

```
~$ sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-mysql : Depends: phpapi-20121212+lfs
              Depends: php5-common (= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.5) but 5.5.19+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, 
I had been using php 5.5.19+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1  but, when I tried to install php5-mysql I got dependency issues.

So then I removed php, php-common, figuring that it would only delete the program files, and leave the config pages alone. (I really like the config I have had)

I restarted the webserver.
Then, I reinstalled php5, and  php5-mysql using the standard repos. I was prompted during install to use the existing config file, which i did.  The installation then successfully completed.

Perhap this can help someone else in a similar situation.

Answer (score -1):

try running `sudo apt-get -f install` it would correct the dependency issues

Comment: I tried that before posting

Comment: can you post the content of your `sources.list` file, there might be some Precise compatible PPA left there, because the package you have is Precise compatible! (5.5.19+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1)

Comment: welcome! you need to solve the issue roots , so that you don't lose future conf files :p